# Zoho Projects API - Auth token

Tags: rest, api, zoho

I have been unable to generate my auth token for accessing Zoho Projects through the API. I had previously made an app that connects to People and Reports, but for some reason, Projects is all the more difficult!

I get an "invalid code" in the step 'Generate access and Refresh Token' in the following link. I have followed each step, and retrieved the code from the URL in the browser I get redirected to after fulfilling the previous step.

https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/get-tickets-api.html

I believe it's not as good explained as it should be, anyway. I don't understand why you have to put a "client id", "client domain" and what is their purpose. I'd love if someone can point me in a better direction about how to do this authentication.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Zoho projects supports only OAuth grant type "authorization_code". The other grant types are not supported.

This is somewhat confusing as other Zoho apps are supporting more grant types.

"authorization_code" is more complicated, but also safer.

for Zoho Projects docs please see https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/get-tickets-api.html

for more infos on OAuth and grant types see https://oauth.net/2/